# Incorrect encoding in Facebook's OpenGraph

Tags: facebook, encoding, facebook-opengraph

I have a web-page here: http://iworker.ru/career/article/446673

When i try to share it on my Facebook account (using like button below) i'm getting an incorrect encoding in og:title and og:description.

The weird thing is that it works fine with another page, like this for example: "iworker.ru/career/article/350527"

I can confirm, that Facebook incorrectly see my content with this debug tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug (og:title and og:description are displayed with incorrect encoding in the tool's output).

Please advise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debug tool is behaving correctly. Your page contains some characters which do not map to UTF-8 charset. See http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fiworker.ru%2Fcareer%2Farticle%2F446673&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 for confirmation of this.

Comment: Yes, that make sense. But why it messes up only "og" tags and not the others? Definitely strange behavior.